# How should I implement callbacks in phoenix with ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

If callbacks will be deprecated https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1114 and Multi isn't implemented yet, how should I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can just call the "callback" function in the changeset.  So for instance, if you have a changeset for creating a product that needs an identifier GUID generated, you may have implemented this with callbacks.

```
defmodule Product do
  before_insert :generate_identifier

  defp generate_identifier(changeset) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Now you can just call it in your changeset function, which is more explicit.

```
defmodule Product do
  def create_changeset(model, attrs) do
    model
    |> cast(attrs, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> generate_identifier
    |> validate_present(:name)
  end

  defp generate_identifier(changeset) do
    ...
  end
end
```

You can pipe into validators and other types of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what callback you are trying to replace.
As Jason mentioned, for the `before_insert`, just call a function in your changeset instead.

If you are trying to replace `before_update`, `after_update` or `after_delete`, create a function that does all your stuff wrapped in a transaction.

I cannot think of a case that cannot be handled this way, but if you do, update your question with a specific use case.

Comment: You could also add an `update_changeset` function that you apply update callbacks in.

Comment: This is indeed good for `before_update`. However, it will not work for `after_update` or `after_delete` if the change needs to saved for the action to be executed.